# Async/Await Cancellation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

Given the following code in an MVC Action Method:

```
    public async Task<PartialViewResult> PatientFilterAll(PatientFilterQuery patientFilterQuery)
    {
        int count = await Task.Run(() => _patientService.GetAllPatientsCount(patientFilterQuery));

        IList<PatientDTO> patients = await Task.Run(() => GetPatientList(patientFilterQuery));

        Cookie.Set("RecordCount", Convert.ToString(count));

        return PartialView("List", patients);
    }
```

The PatientFilterQuery is a set of Drop Down Boxes with criteria for a search. The total count is requested first for client-side paging, followed by the criteria for the search.

If a Drop Down is changed after a request is made, this generates a new request to the Action method. The result is sometimes the original request is fulfilled followed a few seconds later by the response to the second request.

How can I stop the first request and return only the second one?

Comment: You have no control over this on the server.  What the real problem sounds like is why are there two client requests?  Why isn't the first client request aborted (jQuery?)?

Comment: Can't you live with just having the second request override whatever the first request returned?

Comment: The first request is on page load and includes default criteria. Sometimes the user then makes a selection in the drop down for a narrower search.

Comment: The effect is that the default search displays in the list, then changes later. Better if I could stop the first returned list. Also the search is long running, so the user thinks the first result is correct then sees it change up to five or eight seconds later.

Comment: Erik, that is my question. How would I abort the first request?

Comment: How are you triggering this from the client?

Comment: I'd also add that adding `Task.Run()` can starve your IIS server and cause a 500s if you're website has a lot of users (a lot depends on the number of CPUs and IIS configuration).

Comment: @FredChateau I don't know how to abort the first request.  As I stated it's a *Client* issue not a *Server* issue.  As you have provided zero details about how the initial call is done (no technology described, no code example), it is literally impossible to answer the question as it stands without complete guesses.

Comment: I am using jQuery onchange in each drop down to trigger a post to the server.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to change your async design completely. Using `Task.Run` method doesn't mean it's an async operation. [more info](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html)
- If you are using ADO.NET or EF, they have a new set of `real` async methods which don't need `Task.Run` at all. [more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819165.aspx)
- Asynchronous action methods can have a `CancellationToken` parameter. [more info](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4#CancelToken)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: Well, at least it tells something about a bigger problem which is an unnecessary `Task.Run`.

Comment: Thanks for the async info. I'll be sure to review it carefully.